# Having issue writing a mathematical equation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formulas

Stuck on how to perform a simple line formula as below:

```
double profit=0;
double totalPrice=19.25;
int cost = 12;

profit = totalPrice - 2.15(totalPrice * 15 %) - (cost);
```

How can I write the above equation in code I never have done it before it is giving error on `2.15` and `15%`. How do I represent those numbers?

Thank you

Comment: profit = totalPrice - 2.15 * (totalPrice * 0.15) - (cost);

Comment: @user814064 what does that mean?

Comment: It means if you use an asterisk for multiplication in one place, use it everywhere. And 15% is 0.15.

Comment: @user814064 only if you would have posted that as an answer than comment i would have happily accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
profit = totalPrice - 2.15 * (totalPrice * 0.15) - (cost);
```

15% is expressed as 0.15.

Answer (score 3):

```
profit = totalPrice - (2.15 * (totalPrice * .15)) - cost;
```

Comment: ah yes perfect .15 mean same as 15 % :) nice :) made me realize i need to go back to college